# Best Practise for recording thank you letter.I don't have email addresses

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page

On contribution page, what is the best practice for recording "thank you" letters that have been sent, if they are physical letters (snail mail), right now it only shows thank you letters if they are sent via email and if the person has an email address

Comment: what did you do in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom Activity Type and then record such an Activity when you send out a snail mail. You can also use the existing Print/Merge Document activity and generate the PDF via the Activity and hence record it at the same time.